# Open DJVU files on Android (set default app)

Tags: applications, settings, documents

I have an android phone. I have two apps on the phone, both are able to open djvu files ([FBReader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android&hl=en) & [EBookDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ebookdroid&hl=en)). But when I'm trying to open a djvu file in "my file", the android system says that it is unable to find an application toopen the file. 
How I could set a default application to open djvu files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually a problem with bare-bones file managers. Switching to a more feature rich file manager should solve it.

Head to Play Store and try a famous file manager. I can recommend [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) because I own it and use it, and it gives the option of assigning an app for a file type (subject to mime-type limitations).